# Combinatorial Semantics of Addition and Multiplication

Tags: combinatorics

I am reading books on combinatorics, and there are a few nagging difficulties I have in the subject. My biggest questions regard the semantics used in combinatorial problems. Some of them include the following:

**1** How does "making choices" translate into multiplication? For example, suppose we want to give three presents, say a book, a skateboard, and candy, among 8 people. I understand this as a permutation, as one person getting a book, is different than getting the candy or skateboard. Now, my question has to do with the computation of this problem. I understand that we have 8 choices for the first item, 7 choices for the second item, and 6 choices for the third item. Now, every book and professor would just tell me "therefore, there are  $8*7*6=336$" choices. My question is *how* this semantic of choosing translates to the operation of multiplication. I guess I have this problem in general with the sum rule and product rule of counting. How to the semantics of the sum rule and product rule translate to the operations of addition and multiplication?

**2** The book I am using (Combinatorics and Graph Theory), when discussing generating functions, says that addition is "or/disjunction" while multiplication is "and/conjunction" (see page 164 for what I'm talking about), and so $(x+y)$ means "$x$ and $y$" and $(x+y)(x+z)$ means  "$x$ and $y$, or (exclusive) $x$ and $z$". Why exactly is that? Again, how does this translate to the operations of addition and multiplication? Kenneth Bogart in is book "Combinatorics through Guided Discovery" does the same thing on page 81. I can't see this as merely a re-symbolization of boolean connectives since they actually use numbers in some computations.

Thamls in advance for any reply.

Comment: This should answer your question about the "product rule" http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/311142/use-mathematical-induction-to-prove-the-product-rule-for-m-tasks-from-the-produc